# Positioning Text in an image filled png

Tags: iphone

How does one position the text in a pdf using  UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData or  UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile ?

I want to have an image with positioned text and stored as a pdf.

How does one do the positioning and the layout for pdfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for the **drawInRect**-methods in the documentation. UIImage has one and NSString has some variants of this method, that allow you to select a font, alignment etc. These draw in the created PDF graphics context.
The positioning is done with the origin coordinates of the given CGRect.